# Why in expressionengine 2.5.3 am I getting the white screen, when my index page shows up?

Tags: debugging, templates, expressionengine

I am working on a ExpressionEngine site and I installed all the templates, channels, and channel fields. I've also added the channel tags to the templates to point to the respective channel. The only page that shows up is the home page but when you navigate to the other pages nothing but white. I spent all day trying to debug this problem with no success. So could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure `$debug` is set to `1` in your **index.php** file. That way you should see any PHP errors.

Are you [removing index.php from your URLs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/general/remove_index.php.html)? If so, it could be that your server isn't cooperating, especially if you're running EE from a subdirectory, or running PHP as CGI. See the note on the linked docs page for addressing those situations.

Answer (score 2):

I actually found the issue. My channels, templates and page titles weren't the same. Once I made the identical they began to load.